# How to force auto-hotkey v2 to run on an autohotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I recently installed the new Autohotkey v2. I have an existing autohotkey script called `test-v1.ahk`

When I double-click on `test-v1.ahk`, autohotkey is smart enough to detect that the code conforms to v1 syntax and runs autohotkey v1 on it. How to force auto-hotkey v2 to run on `test-v1.ahk`?

Both Autohotkey v1 and v2 are installed on my PC running on Windows 10.

Comment: I would read through the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/) but I can't immediately see anything in there. However, I think renaming the file to something like `test-v1.ahk2` (or any extension) then when Windows asks how to open the file select the `AutoHotkey v2` exe ¯\( ツ )/¯ EDIT: context menu [here](https://imgur.com/a/ToLNLgv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone smart and helpful gave me this answer.

The solution is this
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_Requires.htm

Comment: I had same question when I changed a .bat script to .ahk then commented out everything.  AHK thought it was v1.  huh?  Above bandaged it but I'd still like to know why AHK marks a fully commented ahk script as v1.